# TexShop does not accept the keyboard global configuration

Tags: editors, texshop, auto-completion, macos, keyboard

I have a question, perhaps for Unix/MacOS connoisseurs, or maybe rather for TeX users.

This is my problem: I work with LaTeX almost daily in several languages, mainly English, but also and frequently in Spanish and French. I am also relearning some coding stuff, due to my research in applied mathematics. So I need to have the backslash symbol \ without having to change the rest of the symbols on my keyboard, such as "ñ" or "ç".

The most obvious solution to this problem is to change the keyboard language every time you need to use the \ symbol, but this isn't practical when you're editing a LaTeX document and working on some code at the same time.

Mac has a function to replace text on the keyboard, I've already used it and it works fine for text editors like Pages, but, unfortunately, it doesn't go well for coding or editing LaTeX docs. When I work in the Terminal, with Option+Y it writes the \ , but if I do the same with the LaTeX editor, it prints a ¥. The same thing happens when I work in R with any other mask than the Terminal.

How can I change the settings of just ONE key on the keyboard, without altering the others? How can I customize the keyboard in such a way that this setting remains universal to all programs that Mac uses? Where can I find more information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some legacy Japanese fonts have  ¥ in the \ slot, it used to be quite common to see  ¥ used as the tex escape character. I don't have a mac to test, but does Option+Y work in tex, even if it looks like a yen in the font you are using?

Answer (score 2):

In the Source menu of TeXShop there is a Key Bindings item. The first item is Toggle On/Off. Make sure this has a checkmark next to it, if not, choose that item. Then select the Edit Key Bindings item and you will see the following:

[image]

In the Input box type Option-y (which will cause the `¥` character to appear) and in the output box type `\` to bind that key to the backslash character. You will get a prompt saying that it will override the current binding (which by default is set to enter `\yen`).

There is also a global text replacement function in the MacOS which is accessible via the Keyboard preference pane Text panel in the System Preferences. But not all applications will respect this. For example, I use Atom for coding, and it does not use this functionality, even though other applications do. Of course you can customize Atom directly so it's not that big of a problem. For native MacOS applications the global text replacement is likely to work, but for cross platform apps it may be variable.

Comment: It's also possible to add new key-bindings to the system and all apps that use Apple's text framework will use them. Download `KeyBindings.zip` from [https://herbs.github.io](https://herbs.github.io) for more information.